# How to view Chef Attributes on a Chef Solo Vagrant Node?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I'm in the process of testing a cookbook, and one of the LWRP's seems to not contain an attribute that I am expecting it to. I need to see a list of attributes that are being set on the node. Is there a way to do this within a Vagrant chef-solo node?

I use `kitchen converge` which uses chef-solo to provision a vagrant box on my virtualbox vagrant-provider. The node is thus not registered to a chef-server where I'd normally use `knife node show <node-name>` to view a list of the attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Ssh to your vagrant box and start [chef_shell](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_shell.html). If you run your recipe from there, you will be able to add breakpoints and examine *node* objects, including the available attributes.